# Suspicious deriviatives of $\tan^2(x)$ and $\sec^2(x)$

Tags: calculus

$(\tan^{2}(x))' = 2\tan(x)(\tan(x))' = 2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)$, whereas
$(\sec^{2}(x))' = 2\sec(x)(\sec(x))' = 2\sec(x)(\sec(x)\tan(x)) = 2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)$

Wolfram alpha agrees. According to it "$\tan^2(x)$" derivative is "$2 \sec^2(x) \tan(x)$" of which the integral is "$\sec^2(x)$"

I feel that $\tan^{2}(x)$ and $\sec^{2}(x)$ are different enough functions that they cannot have the same derivative. I also thought that $2$ completely different functions cannot have the same derivative. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Two functions $f$ and $g$ have the same derivatives if and only if there is a constant $c$ such that $f=g+c$. In this case, $\sec^2=\tan^2+1$.

Comment: @azif00 This is strictly speaking only true if both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable everywhere which isn't the case here. If it is not true they need not be seperated by a constant (for example $\frac{1}{x}$ has the same derivative as $\frac{1}{x}+\text{sign}(x)$). However it is true that if $f$ and $g$ are seperated by a constant then they have equal derivatives, that is all that is needed in this case.

Comment: I highly recommend putting both of these functions into Desmos.

Comment: @Fishbane Then add "on an interval" in the above comment claim and this will fix the issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x$$ As the two functions differ only by a constant, they have the same derivative.